# how to convert a column in pandas dataframe from category to date time utc?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have to merge two dataframes created from an arrow file and a csv file. The dataframes have similar column types other than just one column. This column stores dates.

```
some_date
---------
2015-07-03 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-06 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-07 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-08 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-09 00:00:00+00:00
```

When I read the arrow file, the corresponding dataframe column has a type of `datetime64[ns, UTC]` and the csv version of the dataframe has a column types as `category`.

I need to merge these two dataframes. So I convert the csv dataframe for date into `datetime64[ns, UTC]` format.

```
csv_data['some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_data['series_value_date'], utc = True)
```

This works for some dataframes and for some it doesn't.

For example, below csv is being converted just fine into `datetime64[ns, UTC]`.

```
2022-01-08 00:00:00+00:00
2022-01-09 00:00:00+00:00
2022-08-09 00:00:00+00:00
2022-08-10 00:00:00+00:00
2022-08-11 00:00:00+00:00
```

However, the below one doesn't. It stays `category` even after converting it explicitly.

```
2015-07-03 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-06 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-07 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-08 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-09 00:00:00+00:00
2015-07-10 00:00:00+00:00
```

what could be the difference between the csv files here ? Is there a better way for this conversion so that it is uniform across all cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may additionally need `astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]')`:

```
csv_data['some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_data['series_value_date'], utc = True).astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]')
```

Comment: csv_data['some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_data['series_value_date'], utc = True).astype('datetime64[ns]')  gives me error You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and datetime64[ns, UTC].  How do I get datetime64[ns, UTC] instead of datetime64[ns]?

Comment: Ah okay, check the edited version.

Comment: any idea why this additional conversion is needed for some csv and not for the other ?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the example you gave above. It converts them correctly to DateTime in my case. But my guess would be you may read the columns with `dtype='category` in the beginning.  It is also interesting you said the columns are categories in the csv file because `pd.read_csv` almost never assign `category` to a column unless you tell it so

Comment: yep. That's true. I see that after reading csv, it converts all object columns types into category. I am thinking instead of converting csv column to datetime, I can instead convert the arrow dataframe into category. Atleast that's more explicit and will always be consistent.